# Divide 2d Array into squares of size n and calulate mean for each sqaure in Python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, mean

I'm sorry for this easy question. I have a little knot in my head.
I have a 2d-array in python. And I would like to dive this array into squares of size n and compute the mean for each square.
My messy pseudo-code looks more or less like this until now:

```
def mean(pic, n):
    """
    n: size of the square
    """
    npixels_r = pic.height // n
    npixels_c = pic.width // n
    new_pic = picture(npixels_c, npixels_r)
    # fill the new image
    # define the indexes for each qaudrant
    for s in range(0,w,n):
        for z in range(0,h,n):
            vals = []
            # for each pixel in the quadrant
            for i in range(s,s+n):
                for j in range(z, z*n):
                    # get color at each pixel
                    val = pic[i][j]
                    vals.append(val)
            m = mean(vals)
            new_pic.setValue(m)
```

But it's not working. In the first nested for-loop I wanted to iterate over the squares and in the second nested for-loop over each pixel in the old_image and then compute the mean.
This is apparently not a good idea, but I can't think of any  solution at the moment:/

Comment: Don't re-create the wheel here.  :).  `scipy` has an image processing library to do this.  You can convolve with a kernel of the size you want (n x n) with all 1's in it and it will produce what you want.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, but I need to implement it manually;)

Answer (score 2):

You're gonna kick yourself: change `for j in range(z, z*n)` to `for j in range(z, z+n)`

I would use an [image kernel](https://setosa.io/ev/image-kernels/) to solve this one though. You would create an nxn kernel with each pixel value `1/n^2` and apply it to the image. Your proposed solution is essentially the same, but less generalizable (what if you want to do edge finding instead of averaging?)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I'll try this one:) Unfortunately I need to implement it manually